# Excel - Highlight holidays on timesheet based on list of holidays

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting

[image]
I have a list (for the rest of the year) of our recognized holidays at work, I want to highlight the row (just like I have the days off) if the day is one of the holidays. I have the dates for the holidays in text format in row O.

Them being text I figured I could use the same formula I am using for off days

```
=OR(LEFT(TEXT(C$8,"ddd"),2)=LEFT($G$5,2),LEFT(TEXT(C$8,"ddd"),2)=LEFT($H$5,2))
```

I just cant figure it out :/

Comment: If you are manually entering the holiday dates manually I would recommend entering them as an excel date value and you MIGHT save yourself a little grief with text manipulation.  Having said that, there are at least two types of holidays.  I will call one group Static, that occur on the same date every year.  ie July 4th, January 1st, December 25th etc.  The second group can get a little more complicated as they occur on the same day of the month but different dates.  Examples of this would be holidays that occur on say the second Friday of the month.  And if you want to get really complicated

Comment: you can try automating the calculation for easter

Comment: I manually enter the dates because the "Observed Holidays" will not necessarily fall on the holiday itself.  We are union and have specific holidays we get and others we do not.  So having to manually enter all the dates we get off once a year is not really a big deal.  I like them as text ONLY because it's what I understand so far with excel and it works with my previously used formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working off your previous formula I would use something along the lines of the following:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(TEXT(C$8,"mmm"),3)=LEFT($O$3:$O$12,3))*(DAY(C$8)=--RIGHT($O$3:$O$12,2)))
```

Basically the formula will return the value of 1 which is equivalent to true for excel math if the first three letters of the month match and the date's day number match.  All other results should return 0.  It is also imperative that you do not have duplicate holiday dates in your list or the formula will return a value greater than 1.  But there are ways around that too, but that is a follow up question.

Comment: Thank you, this worked wonders. I have changed the payroll date and checked the days, all seems to be working.  I appreciate it.  I'll never have to worry about 2 holidays on the same date because of the way things work here.  Thank you, again.